Send form data request parameters in k6
I am learning k6 and stuck in one of the post requests wherein I need to send the below form data parameters. I tried sending it as normal data by using JSON.stringify() method and by using FormData. But I am not getting valid response. It should be URL encoded. Below is the data.

I verified the same in JMeter and POSTMAN. It works perfectly fine with valid response. But I am struggling in k6.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You forgot to show how you perform your POST request with k6. The post docs plainly state:

Parameter: body
Typed: string / object / ArrayBuffer
Description: Request body; objects will be x-www-form-urlencoded.

That means you don't need to do any encoding yourself, simply pass the object:
http.post(yourUrl, {
  isn: 'testqa',
  JsonString: '… your string …',
});

You might combine that with a dynamically built JsonString value:
JsonString: JSON.stringify({
  username: 'test user',
  password: 'password',
  …
}),

(I cannot copy your input and will certainly not type it, because text from images cannot be copy-pasted)
